# Prevent some users from closing Android service

Tags: android, service

I'm making a service on Android where it will be installed on a phone/tablet. Many people can use that tablet but only selected ones should have right to close the service. How can I achieve this? I googled & found some options:

- Making user accounts: There are lots of apps for this but they do not specify whether service running in one account will run for other accounts also.
- Prompt for password before closing service : There are Many stackoverflow Q.for this but looks impossible.
- Restart service when user closes it : Restarting may lead to loss of data as my service is continuously communicating with other devices to collect data.

**NEW OPTION:**

I have another idea to make it work : I'm will make it system app so that it will warn user when he tries to stop it. For system apps, when user presses the "stop" button from settings, a warning message pops up :" Closing this app may lead to..(blah blah)....". Do you know which intent is thrown to pop up this message? I think I can use that intent here and disable the "OK" option in this message

[image: I want to disable this "OK"].

Comment: Just curious, but why would the worker on factory floor feel compelled to stop the service? (Seems like you edited that line out above). That's not the easiest flow to even get to the "apps" settings screen to find the running process to stop it.

Comment: Since, Android is getting famous day by day worker may know how to do this. Also, for security purpose I want this feature.

Comment: This is a question for whoever is customizing the firmware for your device. If you are attempting to use off-the-shelf hardware for this use case, with the stock ROM, that's a fairly substantial mistake IMHO. Not to mention that an everlasting service is generally an anti-pattern in the first place.

Comment: @CommonsWare Its not a everlasting service. I just want it to be password protected to stop.

Answer (score 6):

Even if the user couldn't stop the service, the phone could still get powered off, run out of battery, or lose network connectivity. It's even conceivable that Android could kill the service process if it ran low on resources.  So the code should be prepared to for handling the potential data loss in those events.

I'm not certain how you detect when the service has been stopped, but there's always [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for periodic polling.

Comment: Other reasons like power off and network failure are rare in factories . To handle low memory situation, I'm going to give more than enough hardware capability. For power off situation, a message will be sent to manager (wo will have access to service). Thanks for pointing out important issues. :)

Answer (score 6):

Preventing a service from closing is nearly impossible. However, you can make that your service **restarts** a soon as it got closed.

Use [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29). As stated in the docs:

> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.)

Return [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) from your `onStartCommand` to restart your service as soon as a user closes your service. In most cases, your service will be restarted in <5s, this however depends on how often your service gets killed successively.

These two methods will make your service nearly unkillable.

Comment: I have made it Foreground and STICKY now. As I already mentioned in my Q., restarting may not be very good idea as it will take few seconds. I may loose data in those seconds. After searching for a long, I agree: "Preventing a service from closing is nearly impossible."

Comment: This will not work if user force stops the app. When that happens your service will not be started until user interacts with app again.

Answer (score 3):

Are you permmited to disable settings?

If so, in your service you could monitorize the running threads and kill the ones that belong to settings (By package name) or just make the system return to the launcher, the user will never reach a context where is able to close processes.

This solution does not irradiate correctness (Google recommend not to do that), but it will prevent the user to even see the option, and for a local (not whole market) app it might be acceptable.

Anyway, if you are able to handle some loss of data (just for a few seconds), I would say you to use the RETURN_STICKY answer.

Comment: That was good suggestion. I have another idea to make it work : I'm making it system app so that it will warn user when he tries to stop it. For system apps, when user presses the "stop" button from settings, a warning message pops up :" Closing this app may lead to..(blah blah)....". Do you know which intent is thrown to pop up this message? I think I can use that intent here and disable the "OK" option in this app.